# Integral convergence implies pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is a simplified version of a question I am looking at, but embarrassingly I can't do this one anyway.

Let's assume $f(x)$ is a decreasing positive function, $f(0)$ is infinite and, moreover, $f(x)$ is comparable to $1/x$ near $x=0$. We look only at positive $x$'s.

**Question**. Assume we know that the limit
$$
\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int\limits_{a}^{2a} f(t)dt
$$
exists as a positive finite number. Does it imply that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(2^{-n})\cdot 2^{-n}
$$
exists?

**Note**: it definitely does not imply that the limit of $xf(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ok with $f$ being not continuous and not *strictly* decreasing, here's a simple enough counter-example. (With a bit more work you can make it continuous and strict, but it distracts from the point.)

Let $f(x)$ be the step-function defined by

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
2^{k} & x \in ( 2^{-k}, 2^{1-k}) \\
2^{k} & x = 2^{-k}, \quad k \text{ is odd} \\
2^{k+1} & x = 2^{-k}, \quad k\text{ is even}
\end{cases} $$

You have that the integral 
$$ \int_a^{2a} f(t) ~dt  = 1 $$
for any $a$.

You have that $2^{-k} f(2^{-k})$ alternating between 1 and 2 and does not converge.

---

Incidentally, the "comparability to $1/x$" in your question is superfluous. Since you assumed decreasing, you have that

$$ a f(2a) \leq \int_a^{2a} f(x) ~dx \leq a f(a) $$

which implies that

$$ \liminf xf(x) \geq \lim \int_a^{2a} f(x) ~dx $$

$$ \limsup xf(x) \leq 2 \lim\int_a^{2a} f(x)~ dx$$

so comparability is automatic, and also the existence of a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $x_n f(x_n)$ converges. (Of course $(2^{-n})$ need not be such a sequence.)

Comment: if one wants a  *strictly* decreasing example, adding 1/x to your f(x) will do it